# Deploy Node project locally on ec2 machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, deployment, git, node.js, jenkins

I have a ec2 Linux-16.04 machine, and Jenkins is installed on it.

I would like to have a Jenkins job to deploy my Node server on the same machine under another user.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add AWS codedeploy as a step in the Jenkins project. The code deploy will copy the nodejs code to the Ec2 instance(s) and run the bash scripts which is configured in appspec.yml (this file and the bash scripts need to be included in the code-deploy package).